# axios request + react hooks inside map function causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios, react-hooks

I'm trying to display the number of Tasks by Project. Calling an axios request with

```
getTasksByProject(_id);
```

causes a loop where "nbrOfTasks" is set infinetly often. How can I prevent this?

```
//Schema
const taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  project: { type: ObjectId, ref: 'Project' },
})

const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  name: String
})
```

The code:

```
const List = ({ match }) => {
  const [projects, setProject] = useState([]);
  const [nbrOfTasks, setNbrOfTasks] = useState();

  const getTasksByProject = ( _id) => {
    axios.get(`/api/tasks/tasksByProject/${_id}`)
    .then(response => {
      setNbrOfTasks(response.data.length);
    })
  }

  const loadProjects = () => {
    axios.get('/api/projects/').then(response => {
      setProject(response.data)
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadProjects();
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <Table singleLine columns={4} striped>
        <Table.Header>
          <Table.Row>
            <Table.HeaderCell>Name</Table.HeaderCell>
            <Table.HeaderCell>#Tasks</Table.HeaderCell>
          </Table.Row>
        </Table.Header>

        <Table.Body>
          {projects.map((project) => {
            const { _id, name, status, description } = project;

            getTasksByProject(_id);

            return (
              <Table.Row key={_id}>
                <Table.Cell>{`${name}`}</Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>{nbrOfTasks}</Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
            )
          })}
        </Table.Body>
      </Table>
    </>
  )
}

export default List;
```

Comment: The reason for infinite loop is that you change state in render with getTasksByProject.  Can api be changed to return tasks of project? If not even you solve the infinite loop problem, your application will have to call getTasksByProject  api  with the number of projects, which is very bad for performance.

Answer (score 0):

hlo kiwi, you cannot setstate inside render function.(you have called getTasksByProject(_id); inside render function which inturns change state and calls render function again and so on). This causes infinite loop.

You can

```
const loadProjects = () => {
                axios.get('/api/projects/').then(response => {
                  response.data.map((project) => {
                        const { _id, name, status, description } = project;
                         axios.get(`/api/tasks/tasksByProject/${_id}`)
                .then(response => {


                })
      //here prepare new array with ({project_id,project_name,task length}) and use this array in render function instead

                })
              }
```

OR better solution would be making a new endpoint which would return  array with ({project_id,project_name,task length})